# NiFi REGISTRY - S3 Bundle Persistence Provider

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am using the Nifi Registry and intend to persist versioning on S3, using the S3BundlePersistenceProvider.

The log does not appear to have any problems with versioning, but it is not possible to see any objects persisting in S3.

'''2020-04-15 04:54:44,775 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry Launching NiFi Registry...
2020-04-15 04:54:44,779 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry Read property protection key from conf/bootstrap.conf
2020-04-15 04:54:44,832 INFO [main] o.a.n.r.security.crypto.CryptoKeyLoader No encryption key present in the bootstrap.conf file at C:\Users\Marcela\Downloads\nifi-registry-0.6.0\conf\bootstrap.conf
2020-04-15 04:54:44,834 INFO [main] o.a.n.r.p.NiFiRegistryPropertiesLoader Loaded 36 properties from C:\Users\Marcela\Downloads\nifi-registry-0.6.0\conf\nifi-registry.properties
2020-04-15 04:54:44,835 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry Loaded 36 properties
2020-04-15 04:54:44,835 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.registry.NiFiRegistry NiFi Registry started without Bootstrap Port information provided; will not listen for requests from Bootstrap

Comment: S3 persistence is for versioned extension bundles, not versioned flows, did you upload a version extension bundle to your registry? https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/user-guide.html#upload-bundle

Comment: I am deeply grateful, I will try to apply.

Comment: I read the link you suggested to me @BryanBende. However, it was not clear to me.
The synchronization of S3BundlePersistenceProvider works like that of GitFlowPersistenceProvider. Every time the developer commits, will the version be saved on S3?

Comment: "Commit" is a logic operation for versioned flows on NiFi side... from registry point of view, all that happens is someone sends the next version and registry saves it in the appropriate persistence provider

Comment: If you send a flow snapshot, it is saved in the flow persistence provider (file system or git)
If you send a bundle, it is saved in the bundle persistence provider (file system or s3)